# Free Jqgrid 500 rows 20 plus columns not Swift scrolling down

Tags: scroll, jqgrid

Would it be possible to tweak the following sample to experience swift movement of scroll bar?
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CWzNFJRSuIQXZBMzM4R0ZQdHc/view?usp=sharing
I noticed setting hdiv.scrollLeft in scrollGrid is actually taking a time, am not understanding we this is required in verticall scroll?

```js
scrollGrid: function (e) { // this must be bDiv
      var bDiv = this, $bTable = getGridComponent(COMPONENT_NAMES.BODY_TABLE, $(bDiv));
      if (e) { e.stopPropagation(); }
      if ($bTable.length === 0) { return true; }
      var gridSelf = $bTable[0].grid;
      if (p.scroll) {
       var scrollTop = bDiv.scrollTop;
       // save last scrollTop of bDiv as property of grid object
       if (gridSelf.scrollTop === undefined) { gridSelf.scrollTop = 0; }
       if (scrollTop !== gridSelf.scrollTop) {
        gridSelf.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        if (gridSelf.timer) { clearTimeout(gridSelf.timer); }
        gridSelf.timer = setTimeout(function () { gridSelf.populateVisible.call($bTable[0]); }, p.scrollTimeout);
       }
      }
      gridSelf.hDiv.scrollLeft = bDiv.scrollLeft;
      if (p.footerrow) {
       gridSelf.sDiv.scrollLeft = bDiv.scrollLeft;
      }
     },
```

Developer tool profiler snapshot with IE9 browser

Function:scrollLeft
Inclusive time (ms):2,141.21
Inclusive time %:79.8
Exclusive time (ms):2,141.21

Comment: Could you describe the problem more exactly? I see no problem with horizontal scrollbar and with paging the data. What problem exist?

Comment: Moreover stackoverflow is not a help forum. You should post code fragments ant try to make your question helpful for other users. There are moderators which controls that and you can be blocked if you don't follow the rules. The questions which have the value only for the person who ask it can be closed.

Comment: Ok, I will change it to be specific. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is still unclear. What you do? How you create jqGrid? Which options you use (no local paging, virtual paging, and so on). You wrote about "500 rows 20 plus columns". What you mean 500 rows and 20 columns? You included the code of `scrollGrid`. What you mean? The demo which you included have no vertical scrollbar. Do you mean slow scrolling **inside of web browser**? You can improve performance by uncommenting `hoverrows: false` option.

Comment: You made some test which shows "Inclusive time (ms):2,141.21 Inclusive time %:79.8". What you did? Which browser you used? You should describe clear the test case. Do you compared the same test case with jqGrid 4.6 or jqGrid 4.7? **Do report new performance problem in free jqGrid or the same problem exist in jqGrid of old versions**? I can help you only if you provide clear test case which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Moreover it has not so much sense to include fragments of code of free jqGrid. You can just post the link like [this one](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2529-L2548) or [this one](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/js/grid.base.js#L1967-L1986). Instead of posting the URL where one can upload the code you could better to provide the working demo which reproduces the problem and the text with clear description of the test case. I made for you http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4z79qmar/1/ which should be close to your code. You can modify it and post URL